# Using SQL parameter when saving to GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopackage

In QGIS 3.0, when I am saving a layer as a GeoPackage when using the Points to Path tool.

[image: Points to Path tool, save to GeoPackage]

The 'Paths' parameter is pre-filled with something like this,

```
ogr:dbname='C:/Paths/Paths.gpkg' table="1119" (geom) sql=
```

Where do I find information on the parameters allowed in this field?  It would be great to use the SQL option to only choose the geometry I want here.  I haven't found a solution in the QGIS docs (the newest ones).  Where else could I look?

Comment: When do you see this? If I do "Layer" "Save As" and choose the format as "GeoPackage", I don't see a "Paths" parameter anywhere. Dialog has Format, File Name, Layer Name, CRS, Extent, Layer Options [DESC, FID, GEOMETRY_NAME,IDENTIFIER, SPATAL_INDEX], Custom options [Data source, Layer]. Can you add a screenshot of what you are doing?

Comment: Good suggestion, question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key aspect is the `ogr` part - that tells you that you're in GDAL/OGR land. Its a happy place, with two kinds of SQL support.

Firstly, there is the old SQL, which you can find documented at http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html

Then there is the new SQLite kind, which you can find documented at http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

Comment: e.g sql='SELECT * FROM streams WHERE name IS NOT NULL'